# how to get Docusign Read-Only Checkbox Tabs to not render broken

Tags: docusignapi

I have a template on Docusign that has boxed-out spaces for checkboxes on the underlying pdf, that we've put checkbox tabs on in read-only.

[image: pdf boxes]   [image: boxes with checkbox tabs]

The problem is read-only checkbox tabs render as a capital X in a fixed size textbox (with a white opaque background), and we can't consistently align it to the boxes on the document.

[image: badX1] [image: badX2] [image: badX3] (this represents zooming in to 400% and aligning the boxes as best as possible)

What would make the most sense is to get rid of the white background, which seems to be impossible given the formatting options of [font, font size, bold, italics, underline, font color].

Barring that, let me show you what happens when you use all of the available font sizes on checkboxes.

[image: WILD Xs] as you can see, there's an immutable white textbox containing a fixed-size X superimposed on top of a perfectly well behaving arbitrarily sized X with transparency. This issue also applies to other formatting choices, and to not read-only checkboxes

[image: editable] [image: bold] [image: italics]

Using the [official python package](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client/blob/96a189afe442191d95e83fbc15462bfb3fce43cb/docusign_esign/models/checkbox.py), or changes on the template, how do you make either transparent-background, or legible checkboxes of arbitrary size?

Comment: I am not able to understand what your complete issue, is it that ReadOnly `X` not covering correctly your Document checkbox placeholder?

Comment: There are 2 Xs. An underlying one that behaves how you’d expect, and an unwanted superimposed one. The superimposed one has an opaque white background that users are complaining about making the boxes of the document inconsistent and confusing. It also doesn’t seem to be editable in any way. On other signer views it isn’t there and isn’t a problem, but if the checkbox is assigned to your signing role, there it is.

Comment: Anything else I can do to clarify?

Comment: Strangely I am not superimposed or 2 Xs, for me its only one for the signer to whom ReadOnly checkbox is assigned.

Comment: correct. namely, the customers who are voicing opinions that I should be preventing such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a text-tab instead and make it read-only with the 'X' or 'x' where your checkbox is (or if you prefer √ character). So a text-tab readonly can have the value you want it to have.

Comment: SO: fun behavior of text-tabs. read-only text tabs and checkboxes do the same thing within a signing view. There's a UI element with the standard size tab on top of the document, and the contents accurately baked onto the underlying PDF.